# ORACLE Data Provider Not showing up as an Option

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle

I am trying to use ADO.NET Entity DATA model (edmx) to connect to Oracle, i have installed the [Oracle data provider from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

But i do not see the data provider as an option when i try to add a new connection for the ADO entity data model.
However I can see the Oracle data provider when i am trying to connect to the DB using from the sever explorer in VS 2010.

Any ideas ?

Comment: i had to install this beta version to get it to work.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to install this beta version to get it to work. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html

Comment: The provided link is no longer active